# snapshot.val() returns undefined, but it logs correctly. Node.js firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I dont know why, but when i return the object in snapshot.val() it doesn't return anything to my front, but when i console.log() it, it shows the object correctly. Here's how i'm returning it:

```
function Loggear({ email, password }) {
  db.ref("Usuarios")
    .orderByChild("email")
    .equalTo(email)
    .on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot.val())
      return snapshot.val();
    });
}
```

How it shows my object on console.log():

```
{
  ciudad: 'Buenos Aires',
  codigoPostal: '1000',
  direccionCalle: 'la casa de tomas',
  direccionNumero: '1',
  documento: '1',
  email: 'firebase@pruebita.com',
  fechaNacimiento: '1111-01-01',
  nombreCompleto: 'firebase',
  password: 'contraseña',
  telefonoCelular: '1233'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to fetch data a single time, use [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) instead of [on()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#on), as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#node.js_8).  `on()` sets up a persistent listener at some database location, and will invoke your callback function every time something changes at that location.  That's not what you want.  Instead use `once()`, which returns promise that resolves with the snapshot of data:

```
function Loggear({ email, password }) {
  return db.ref("Usuarios")
    .orderByChild("email")
    .equalTo(email)
    .once("value", (snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot.val())
      return snapshot.val();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because you are not returning any value from the Loggear function itself. The value from the on child added is only returned to the scope of Loggear. You will have to return it from the function itself, i.e.

```
function Loggear({ email, password }) {
  return db.ref("Usuarios")
    .orderByChild("email")
    .equalTo(email)
    .on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot.val())
      return snapshot.val();
    });
}
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunetly, that return a [function] for some reason. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As Doug Stevenson said, the on function will return the event listener. This will have to be changed to .once()